# How to inject dependency in datasource with ejb3 and annotations

Tags: java, jboss, dependency-injection, ejb, struts

```
@Override
protected ActionForward unspecified(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:jboss/STRUTS-DS");

    dataSource.getConnection();

    SessionBean sessionBean = new SessionBean();
    sessionBean.testConnection();
    return mapping.findForward("list");
}
```

in the Action, works with lookup, problem occurred in `SessionBean`

```
@Stateless
    public class SessionBean {

        @PersistenceContext(???)
        EntityManager entityManager;

        @Resource(???)
        DataSource dataSource;

        public void testConnection() {
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
                Connection connection = null;

                try {
                        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
                        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("drop table test");
                        preparedStatement.execute();

                        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE example (id INT,data VARCHAR(100));");
                        preparedStatement.execute();

                        System.out.println("Done");

                } catch (SQLException sqlE) {
                        throw new EJBException(sqlE);
                } finally {
                        try {
                                if (preparedStatement != null) {
                                        preparedStatement.close();
                                }
                        } catch (Exception e) {}
                        try {
                                if (connection != null) {
                                        connection.close();
                                }
                        } catch (Exception e) {}
                }

        }

    }
```

**I'm trying inject this.
In my datasource never injected, what I put in Resource ?**

Comment: If you are instantiating your `SessionBean`, you can't use any injection - for that to work, it has to be created by the EJB container.

Comment: youre right, the problem is I cant use the annotation EJB and Inject in Action [error: The annotation EJB is disallowed for this location]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try injecting `DataSource` in the stateless bean with it's JNDI name like

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/STRUTS-DS")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

You also need to inject this stateless into the client with `@EJB` or `@Inject` annotation or also with JNDI lookup, these are the only ways how can you be sure that container will correctly inject all the dependencies (the `DataSource` in your case) into the bean.

Comment: I cant use annotation `@EJB` and `@Inject` in Action and as @andersschuller say cant instantiating my `SessionBean` and use dependence injection. I need another solution for this.